# Sqlite database lock error using c# application

Tags: c#

I n my c# application , i am using sqlite as backend. when i perform simple insert query it takes me too long and end up with database is locked message..I deployed my application in stage server and performing the action remotely..Below is my code please help.

```
String sqlExpr = "INSERT INTO item (id, typeid, ownerid, created, modifiedby, modified,active,imageuploaded,logouploaded,language_item) VALUES (@Id,@type_TypeId ,@db_currentUser,@dates,@db_id ,@modified,@active_status,@image,@logo,@language)";

                    //using (SQLiteCommand _insertItem = new SQLiteCommand())
                    //{
                    SQLiteCommand _insertItem = new SQLiteCommand();
                        _insertItem.CommandText = sqlExpr;
                        _insertItem.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Id", Id);
                        _insertItem.Parameters.AddWithValue("@type_TypeId", type.TypeId);
                        _insertItem.Parameters.AddWithValue("@db_currentUser", db.currentUser.id);
                        _insertItem.Parameters.AddWithValue("@dates", DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"));
                        _insertItem.Parameters.AddWithValue("@db_id", db.currentUser.id);
                        _insertItem.Parameters.AddWithValue("@modified", DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"));
                        _insertItem.Parameters.AddWithValue("@active_status", active_status);
                        _insertItem.Parameters.AddWithValue("@image", "false");
                        _insertItem.Parameters.AddWithValue("@logo", "false");
                        _insertItem.Parameters.AddWithValue("@language", language);
                        rowsAffected = db.ExecuteNonQuerySQL(_insertItem);
                        db.Close();


 public int ExecuteNonQuerySQL(SQLiteCommand cmd)
        {
            int ireturn = 0;

            if (conn.State != ConnectionState.Open)//the connection is individual for each session so no need of lock .added the code on 2011-11-08 by Sangeetha
                Open(DataFile);
            //SQLiteConnection C = new SQLiteConnection("Data Source=database.db;Version=3;New=False;Compress=True;");

            using (SQLiteTransaction dbtrans = conn.BeginTransaction(IsolationLevel.ReadCommitted))
            {
                using (SQLiteCommand cmd1 = (SQLiteCommand)cmd.Clone())
                {

                    cmd.Dispose();
                    cmd1.Connection = conn;
                    cmd1.Transaction = dbtrans;
                    ireturn = cmd1.ExecuteNonQuery();
                    dbtrans.Commit();
                    cmd1.Dispose();
                }
            }


            return ireturn;
        }
```

Thank you

Comment: what exactly is the error message and error code?

Comment: database file is locked..This is the error i am getting..

Comment: why pass the SQLcommand to the method and clone it?  Why not just create it from scratch each time?  keep the connection open, but not the command

Comment: clone is used because SQLiteCommand _insertItem = new SQLiteCommand();
 is created in different class.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17592671/sqlite-database-locked-exception

Answer (score 0):

Maybe before you have opened a connection and it's still opened. Make sure, all connections and commands are disposed (use USING statement) and close every reader before exiting function.

Or migrate to 'oledb' provider (MS ACCESS)