# SQLite Database Locked exception

Tags: c#, .net, sqlite, ado.net, system.data.sqlite

I am getting **Database is locked** exception from **SQLite** for some queries only.

Below is my code:
When I execute any select statement it works fine.
When I am executing any write statement on `Jobs` Table it also works fine.

This works fine:

```
ExecuteNonQuery("DELETE FROM Jobs WHERE id=1");
```

But the same way if I am executing queries for `Employees` table it is throwing an exception that **database is locked**.
This throws Exception:

```
ExecuteNonQuery("DELETE FROM Employees WHERE id=1");
```

Below are my functions:

```
public bool OpenConnection()
{
    if (Con == null)
    {
        Con = new SQLiteConnection(ConnectionString);
    }
    if (Con.State == ConnectionState.Closed)
    {
        Con.Open();
        //Cmd = new SQLiteCommand("PRAGMA FOREIGN_KEYS=ON", Con);
        //Cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        //Cmd.Dispose();
        //Cmd=null;
        return true;
    }
    if (IsConnectionBusy())
    {
        Msg.Log(new Exception("Connection busy"));
    }
    return false;
}

public Boolean CloseConnection()
{
    if (Con != null && Con.State == ConnectionState.Open)
    {
        if (Cmd != null) Cmd.Dispose();
        Cmd = null;
        Con.Close();
        return true;
    }

    return false;
}

public Boolean ExecuteNonQuery(string sql)
{
    if (sql == null) return false;
    try
    {
        if (!OpenConnection())
            return false;
        else
        {
            //Tx = Con.BeginTransaction(IsolationLevel.ReadCommitted);
            Cmd = new SQLiteCommand(sql, Con);
            Cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            //Tx.Commit();
            return true;
        }
    }
    catch (Exception exception)
    {
        //Tx.Rollback();
        Msg.Log(exception);
        return false;
    }
    finally
    {
        CloseConnection();
    }
}
```

This is the Exception: 
At line 103 : `Cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();`

> Exception Found:
>         Type: System.Data.SQLite.SQLiteException
>        Message: database is locked
>       database is locked
>        Source: System.Data.SQLite
>
> Stacktrace:    at System.Data.SQLite.SQLite3.Step(SQLiteStatement stmt)
>          at System.Data.SQLite.SQLiteDataReader.NextResult()
>          at System.Data.SQLite.SQLiteDataReader..ctor(SQLiteCommand cmd, CommandBehavior behave)
>          at System.Data.SQLite.SQLiteCommand.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior behavior)
>          at System.Data.SQLite.SQLiteCommand.ExecuteNonQuery()
>          at TimeSheet6.DbOp.ExecuteNonQuery(String sql) in d:\Projects\C# Applications\Completed Projects\TimeSheet6\TimeSheet6\DbOp.cs:line 103

Comment: Make sure you close the connection are executing your request.

Comment: Yes I have closed all the connections and disposed the command objects also.

Comment: I have done a lot of debugging behind this. This doesn't seem to be a problem of open connection.

Comment: It only allow one connection open at a time so better to use `using` statement..

Answer (score 103, accepted):

Somewhere along the way a connection is getting left open. Get rid of `OpenConnection` and `CloseConnection` and change `ExecuteNonQuery` to this:

```
using (SQLiteConnection c = new SQLiteConnection(ConnectionString))
{
    c.Open();
    using (SQLiteCommand cmd = new SQLiteCommand(sql, c))
    {
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
    }
}
```

Further, change the way you **read** data to this:

```
using (SQLiteConnection c = new SQLiteConnection(ConnectionString))
{
    c.Open();
    using (SQLiteCommand cmd = new SQLiteCommand(sql, c))
    {
        using (SQLiteDataReader rdr = cmd.ExecuteReader())
        {
            ...
        }
    }
}
```

**Do not attempt,** to manage connection pooling on your own like you are here. First, it's much more complex than what you have coded, but second, it's handled already inside the `SQLiteConnection` object. Finally, if you're not leveraging `using`, you're **not disposing** these objects properly and you end up with issues like what you're seeing now.

Comment: @coding, yeah. There are always other ways to lock files, but improperly handling the connection objects (like your original code was) is the prime suspect.

Comment: Not closing/disposing the SQLiteDataReader was the problem in my case, despite using using statements for the connection and the command. Thanks for ending the frustration!

Answer (score 14):

You can use 'using' statement as below, that will make sure connection & command disposed correctly even in exception

```
private static void ExecuteNonQuery(string queryString)
{
    using (var connection = new SQLiteConnection(
               ConnectionString))
    {
        using (var command = new SQLiteCommand(queryString, connection))
        {
            command.Connection.Open();
            command.ExecuteNonQuery();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 11):

You should close your DataReader before attempting to write any data to the database. Use:

```
dr.Close();
```

after you finish using the DataReader.

Comment: That was it for me - I had a reader that wasn't wrapped in a "using" block, and it was locking the DB for subsequent writes.

Answer (score 6):

In my case it was very stupid of me, I was making changes in SQLite browser and did not click on write changes, which locked the DB to be modified by the services. After I clicked the Write changes button, all the post request worked as expected.

Comment: Wow, That was my fault too. **Be aware** click on `Write changes` on `SQLite browser` if it is running and there are any unsaved changes!

Answer (score 2):

A lot of helpful posts here for folks that may have forgotten to clean up a dangling connection, but there is another way this can happen: SQLite does not support concurrent INSERTs; if you issue two INSERTs at the same time the will be processed in serial. When the INSERTs are quick this is fine, but if an INSERT takes longer than the timeout the second INSERT can fail with this message.

I had this happen when I used a long running transaction to accumulate a bunch of INSERTs into one big commit. Basically I locked the database from any other activity during the transaction. Switching to `journal_mode=WAL` will allow concurrent writes and reads, but not concurrent writes.

I got rid of the long running transaction and let each INSERT autocommit, and that solved my problem.

Answer (score 1):

Mine was caused by not closing a SqliteDataReader when calling HasRows().

I had this:

```
 using (SQLiteConnection connection = new SQLiteConnection(DbPath))
 {
    connection.Open();
    string sql = $"SELECT * FROM ...";
    using (SQLiteCommand command = new SQLiteCommand(sql, connection))
    {
        return command.ExecuteReader().HasRows;
    }

    connection.Close();
}
```

But needed to put a using around the ExecuteReader like so:

```
using (SQLiteDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader())
{
      return command.ExecuteReader().HasRows;
}
```

Even though the DbConnection was being disposed and re-created each time the db was still being kept locked by the reader.

Answer (score 0):

I was also getting the same error here:

```
if (new basics.HindiMessageBox(HMsg, HTitle).ShowDialog()==true)
{
    SQLiteConnection m_dbConnection = new SQLiteConnection(MainWindow.con);
    m_dbConnection.Open();
    sql = "DELETE FROM `users`  WHERE `id`=" + SelectedUser.Id;
    command = new SQLiteCommand(sql, m_dbConnection);
    command.ExecuteNonQuery();
    m_dbConnection.Close();
    LoadUserDG();
}
```

but when I just changed SQLiteConnection declaration location

```
public partial class User : Window
{
    SQLiteCommand command;
    string sql;
    AddUser AddUserObj;
    List<basics.users> usersList;
    basics.users SelectedUser;
    SQLiteConnection m_dbConnection;

    // ...

    private void DeleteBtn_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        // ...
        if (new basics.HindiMessageBox(HMsg, HTitle).ShowDialog()==true)
        {
            m_dbConnection = new SQLiteConnection(MainWindow.con);
            m_dbConnection.Open();
            sql = "DELETE FROM `users`  WHERE `id`=" + SelectedUser.Id;
            command = new SQLiteCommand(sql, m_dbConnection);
            command.ExecuteNonQuery();
            m_dbConnection.Close();
            LoadUserDG();
        }
}
```

Everything is fine now.
I hope this may work for you, too.
If someone can say how this happened, I would like to know the details to improve my knowledge, please.

Comment: You should use "Using" wherever possible! Like Mike Perrenoud and Damith showed you. "Using" was invented for control / safety reasons, you should really use it.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue when loading a lot of data to different tables from multiple threads.
When trying to do the inserts I was getting database locked because the program was doing too many insert too fast and SQLite didn't have time to complete each transaction before another one came.

The insert are done through threading because I didn't want the interface to be locked and wait for the insert to be done.

My solution is to use BlockingCollection with ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem.
This allows me to free the interface while doing the inserts.
All the insert are queued and executed in FIFO (First In First Out) order.
Now the database is never locked while doing any SQL transaction from any thread.

```
public class DatabaseQueueBus
{
    private BlockingCollection<TransportBean> _dbQueueBus = new BlockingCollection<TransportBean>(new ConcurrentQueue<TransportBean>());
    private CancellationTokenSource __dbQueueBusCancelToken;

    public CancellationTokenSource _dbQueueBusCancelToken { get => __dbQueueBusCancelToken; set => __dbQueueBusCancelToken = value; }

    public DatabaseQueueBus()
    {
        _dbQueueBusCancelToken = new CancellationTokenSource();
        DatabaseQueue();

    }

    public void AddJob(TransportBean dto)
    {
        _dbQueueBus.Add(dto);
    }

    private void DatabaseQueue()
    {

        ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem((param) =>
        {
            try
            {
                do
                {
                    string job = "";
                    TransportBean dto = _dbQueueBus.Take(_dbQueueBusCancelToken.Token);
                    try
                    {
                        job = (string)dto.DictionaryTransBean["job"];
                        switch (job)
                        {
                            case "SaveClasse":
                                //Save to table here
                                break;
                            case "SaveRegistrant":
                                //Save Registrant here
                                break;
                          
                        }
                    }
                    catch (Exception ex)
                    {//TODO: Handle this exception or not

                    }

                } while (_dbQueueBusCancelToken.Token.IsCancellationRequested != true);
            }
            catch (OperationCanceledException)
            {

            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {

            }
        });
    }
}
```

The inserts are done this way, but without the queuing I was still getting the lock issue.

```
using (SQLiteConnection c = new SQLiteConnection(BaseDal.SQLiteCon))
        {
            c.Open();
            using (SQLiteCommand cmd = new SQLiteCommand(sql, c))
            {
                cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            }
            c.Close();
        }
```