# sqlite database is locked on insertion

Tags: c#, sqlite, freeze

There's a simple code

```
var insert = 
    @"INSERT INTO [files] (
     [Name],
     [FullName],
     [MD5])
     VALUES (@Name, @FullName, @MD5);";
using (var con = _db.OpenConnection())
{
    using (var cmd = con.CreateCommand())
    {
        cmd.CommandText = insert;
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Name", item.Name);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@FullName", item.FullName);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@MD5", item.MD5);
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
    }
 }
```

applications hangs for some time when executing

```
cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

and then fails with exception "database is locked".
Why this is happening? Application is not multithreaded. DB file is just-created.

Comment: Check your Task Manager and see if there is a process holding on to your SQLite database.

Comment: What does OpenConnection() do?

Comment: There is some other connection with an active transaction. This might be from the same or another process.

Comment: Yes, you're right. Before this code there was call to SqlCommand.ExecuteReader. Though connection and command which created this reader were disposed, this reader itself wasn't disposed. After fixing with "using(reader)" connection was closed properly and error above disappeared.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Problem solved.
Before this code there was call to SqlCommand.ExecuteReader(). Though connection and command which created this reader were disposed, this reader itself wasn't disposed. After fixing with "using(reader)" connection was closed properly and error above disappeared.

In total: DataReader can still hold a connection even if connection and SqlCommand were disposed explicitly.

Comment: Can you share please example of inserting data?

Comment: no, unfirtunately, I leaved this project and thrown the code away.

Answer (score 2):

Be aware to click on `Write changes` on **SQLite browser** if it is running and there are any unsaved changes!

[image: Sqlite browser]

In my case it was very stupid of me, I was making changes in SQLite browser and did not click on write changes, which locked the DB to be modified by the services. After I clicked the Write changes button, all the post request worked as expected.
According to @Rohan Shenoy in this topic: [SQLite Database Locked exception](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17592671/sqlite-database-locked-exception/17592858#17592858)

Answer (score -2):

Your code lacks the call to `prepare()`

```
int i=0;
        try
        {
            Conectar();
            SQLiteCommand comando = new SQLiteCommand(con);
            comando.CommandText = "INSERT INTO EMPRESA (NAME,ESTADO) VALUES (@name, @estado)";
            comando.Parameters.AddWithValue("@name", art.NAME);
            comando.Parameters.AddWithValue("@estado", art.ESTADO);
            comando.Prepare();
            con.Open();
            i = comando.ExecuteNonQuery();
            con.Close();
        }
        catch (SQLiteException ex)
        {
            string a = ex.Message.ToString();   
            throw;
        }

        return i;
```

Comment: This is an Englsh speaking forum. Please write only in English.