# How to solve the SQLite "Database is locked" in C#?

Tags: c#, sqlite

When I update some data, sometimes it throws a exception: `Database is locked`. 
The code below:

```
public int DisableSalesBySalesID(string SalesID)
{
    int count = 0;
    try
    {
        using (SQLiteConnection conn = new SQLiteConnection(ConnectionString))
        {
            conn.Open();
            string sql = @"update SalesMaster set Disabled = '1' where SalesID=@SalesID";
            using (SQLiteCommand cmd = new SQLiteCommand(sql, conn))
            {
                cmd.Parameters.Add(new SQLiteParameter("@SalesID", SalesID));
                count = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            }
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
    }
    return count;
}
```

And, it depends on `SalesID`. Some `SalesID` will be OK, but the others will make the exception. Why?

Comment: Presumably another query has a lock for that SalesID at the moment you run the update.  This error specifically means it is your own process, not a different process, creating the lock.  Do you have a SELECT still pending when you call this code?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17592671/sqlite-database-locked-exception?rq=1

Comment: You could apply the all mighty hackish approach to your query, `WITH (NOLOCK)` or `(nolock)`.  Except that would be applied to almost all your `SELECT` queries.

Comment: Does your program have multiple threads that connect to the same database?

Comment: Thank you everyone , I knew the program has multiple threads that connect to the same database or the connection doesn't dispose will make this problem. But I have focus on the update command, and forgot the select command before and after the update command. It has been resolved when i put the using blocks in the select command. Thank you！

Answer (score 0):

a common cause is that you have a dangling sqlcommand. sqlcommands hold locks on the database. same for sqlreaders. Make sure they are all in using blocks