# C# sqlite delete rows not work when there is no rows in that table

Tags: c#, sqlite

I am tring to delete one table's all record using C#.

```
SQLiteConnection sql_con = new SQLiteConnection("Data Source=test.db3;Version=3;New=false;Compress=true;");
        SQLiteCommand sql_cmd;
        sql_con.Open();
        sql_cmd = sql_con.CreateCommand();
        sql_cmd.CommandText = "delete from table1";
        sql_cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        sql_con.Close();
```

It works when there are rows existing in table1. However if there is no rows in table1, the code will break at
    sql_cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
What do I miss?

Comment: What do you mean "break"? Does it throw an error? What error?

Comment: @RonBeyer it throws an error after few mins saying that database is locked. BTW there is no truncate command in SQLite.

Comment: I realized that after posting it, I was thinking SQL... It isn't possible that this is being called more than once on multiple threads? Have you tried running that command in an SQLite console or management utility?

Comment: @RonBeyer thats the point. I ran it in a SQLite management utility(DB brower for SQLite). It works perfectly, When I move the command to C#, It won't work. What I can do is that check if there has rows or not before I delete it, and If it does, I ll go delete it.

Comment: You may have a connection that is left open, see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17592671/sqlite-database-locked-exception) which isn't really the same issue, but it is good practice to use `using` if you get exceptions elsewhere that are leaving connections open.

Answer (score 0):

It is critically important to wrap all your disposable objects in `using` blocks. SQLite will NOT fully close the connection until the objects are disposed. Try this code:

```
using (SQLiteConnection sql_con = new SQLiteConnection("Data Source=test.db3;Version=3;New=false;Compress=true;"))
{
    sql_con.Open();
    using (SQLiteCommand sql_cmd = sql_con.CreateCommand())
    {
        sql_cmd.CommandText = "delete from table1";
        sql_cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
    }
}
```